# Дебаг цикла в template в django

Tags: django

``

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block body_block %}
<h2>тестовые тесты</h2>
<ol>
<li>{{ food_detail.food_name }}</li>
</ol>
<h3>Комментари</h3>
<ol>
  {% for comments in food_detail.Food_r.all %}
    <li>{{ comments.text_t }}</li>
  {% empty %}
    <li>нет Комментариев</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ol>
{% endblock%}
```

``

как мне понять почему этот цикл выдает пустой результат? 
food_detail.food_name - данные возвращают

```
class Comments_Food(models.Model):
    date_d          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,
                                            verbose_name="Время")
    Food_r          = models.ForeignKey(Food,
                                        models.DO_NOTHING,
                                        verbose_name="Блюдо")
```

Comment: Что такое food_detail?

Comment: часть view.pyclass FoodDetailView(DetailView):
       context_object_name = "food_detail"
       model = Food

Comment: Если в модели Food не прописано никаких связей с Comments_Food, значит название обратной связи для ForeignKey генерируется автоматически по названию модели и нужно использовать что-то вроде `{% for comments in food_detail.comments_food_set.all %}`

Comment: Food_r          = models.ForeignKey(Food,
                                        models.DO_NOTHING,
                                        verbose_name="Блюдо")

Comment: Да, именно поэтому связь в обратную сторону будет сгенерирована как `comments_food_set` (если я ничего не напутал)

Comment: а где в документации джанго пр это можно почитать?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects

Comment: Можно ли использовать агрегированные функции внутри темлейтов?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по комментариям к вопросу, нужно вывести связанные объекты для экземпляра `Food`, который в шаблоне представлен как `food_detail`.

```
{% for comment in food_detail.comments_food_set.all %}
    <li>{{ comment.text_t }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>нет Комментариев</li>
{% endfor %}
```

***P.S.*** Непонятно, что такое `text_t`? В шаблоне в переменной `comment` будет храниться экземпляр класса `Comments_Food`. Поэтому из `comment` можно получить доступ к каждому полю модели.

---

Советую задать `related_name` для обратной связи и задавать имена атрибутов (полей) в стиле `snake_case`, а название классов - в `CamelCase`. Тогда модель и шаблон будут выглядеть следующим образом:

**models**

```
class CommentsFood(models.Model):
    date_d = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,
                                  verbose_name="Время")
    food_r = models.ForeignKey(Food,
                               models.DO_NOTHING,
                               verbose_name="Блюдо",
                               related_name="comments")
```

**template**

```
{% for comment in food_detail.comments.all %}
    <li>{{ comment.text_t }}</li>
{% empty %}
    <li>нет Комментариев</li>
{% endfor %}
```